# Recommended Mac GUI data entry tools for populating SQLite databases for iPhone app use?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, desktop, data-entry

While making an iPhone app that refers to a (not yet existing) SQLite db

Are there any good, cheap programs for data entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite manager for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817). An awesome plugin for FireFox which is a full-featured management tool for SQLite database.

Comment: When I saw the question I was about to exactly the same answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I've published instructions for [how to run the Firefox SQLite Manager outside of Firefox](http://www.kiveo.net/blog/mac-sqlite-manager-standalone-app/), since FF hase become so bloated in the last few releases. It's really easy and I've even compiled a DMG for the sqlite gui if anyone wants it.